# Spring BeanUtils is not copying the list after upgrading spring boot version

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I'm working on maven multi modules project spring boot version: `2.1.3.RELEASE` I used Spring `BeanUtils` and it was doing its job while I upgraded to the latest spring boot version `2.6.6` `BeanUtils` seems like it doesn't copy the list I've searched on documentations maybe there was a problem on versions but I found nothing Here is the output before and after upgrading:

**Before (2.1.3.RELEASE):**

```json
    {
        "releveBancaireId": 1,
        "dateReception": "2022-04-08",
        "label": "RELEVE_1",
        "nbrLignes": 15,
        "nbrOperationCredit": 7,
        "nbrOperationDebit": 0,
        "soldeInitial": 145.20,
        "soleFinal": 158.36,
        "lignereleve": [
            {
                "ligneReleveId": 1,
                "dateOperation": "2022-04-08",
                "operationNature": "Virement",
                "montant": 14789.00,
                "creditDebit": "C",
                "ref": 15987456,
                "refPaiment": 1569873,
                "modePaiment": "MASTERCARD",
                "releveBancaire": {
                    "releveBancaireId": 1,
                    "dateReception": "2022-04-08",
                    "label": "RELEVE_1",
                    "nbrLignes": 15,
                    "nbrOperationCredit": 7,
                    "nbrOperationDebit": 0,
                    "soldeInitial": 145.20,
                    "soleFinal": 158.36
                }
            },
            {
                "ligneReleveId": 2,
                "dateOperation": "2022-04-08",
                "operationNature": "Cheque",
                "montant": 14789.00,
                "creditDebit": "C",
                "ref": 15987456,
                "refPaiment": 1569873,
                "modePaiment": "MASTERCARD",
                "releveBancaire": {
                    "releveBancaireId": 1,
                    "dateReception": "2022-04-08",
                    "label": "RELEVE_1",
                    "nbrLignes": 15,
                    "nbrOperationCredit": 7,
                    "nbrOperationDebit": 0,
                    "soldeInitial": 145.20,
                    "soleFinal": 158.36
                }
            },
            {
                "ligneReleveId": 3,
                "dateOperation": "2022-04-08",
                "operationNature": "Espece",
                "montant": 14789.00,
                "creditDebit": "C",
                "ref": 15987456,
                "refPaiment": 1569873,
                "modePaiment": "MASTERCARD",
                "releveBancaire": {
                    "releveBancaireId": 1,
                    "dateReception": "2022-04-08",
                    "label": "RELEVE_1",
                    "nbrLignes": 15,
                    "nbrOperationCredit": 7,
                    "nbrOperationDebit": 0,
                    "soldeInitial": 145.20,
                    "soleFinal": 158.36
                }
            }
        ]
    },
```

**After (latest version : 2.6.6)**

```json
    {
        "releveBancaireId": 1,
        "dateReception": "2022-04-08",
        "label": "RELEVE_1",
        "nbrLignes": 15,
        "nbrOperationCredit": 7,
        "nbrOperationDebit": 0,
        "soldeInitial": 145.20,
        "soleFinal": 158.36,
        "lignereleve": []
    },
```

**My Entities:**

```java
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Table(name = "RELEVEBANCAIRE")
    @Entity
    @ToString
    @Builder
    public class ReleveBancaireEntity{
    
    
    
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Long releveBancaireId;
        @CreationTimestamp
        @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
        private Date dateReception;
        private String label;
        private int nbrLignes;
        private int nbrOperationCredit;
        private int nbrOperationDebit;
        private BigDecimal soldeInitial;
        private BigDecimal soleFinal;
        @OneToMany(cascade= CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy = "releveBancaire", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        @JsonIgnoreProperties("releveBancaire")
        @JsonIgnore
        private List<LigneReleveEntity> lignereleve = new ArrayList<>();
    
    @Table(name = "LIGNERELEVE")
    @Entity
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PUBLIC)
    @NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PUBLIC)
    @ToString
    public class LigneReleveEntity{
    
    
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    
        private Long ligneReleveId;
        @CreationTimestamp
        @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
        private Date dateOperation;
        private String operationNature;
        private BigDecimal montant;
        private String creditDebit;
        private int ref;
        private int refPaiment;
        private String modePaiment;
        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        @JoinColumn(name = "FK_releveBancaire", referencedColumnName = "releveBancaireId")
        @JsonIgnoreProperties("lignereleve")
        private ReleveBancaireEntity releveBancaire;
```

**Models:**

```
@Builder
public class ReleveBancaire{


    private Long releveBancaireId;
    private Date dateReception;
    private String label;
    private int nbrLignes;
    private int nbrOperationCredit;
    private int nbrOperationDebit;
    private BigDecimal soldeInitial;
    private BigDecimal soleFinal;
    private List<LigneReleve> lignereleve = new ArrayList<>();

public class LigneReleve{

    private Long ligneReleveId;
    private Date dateOperation;
    private String operationNature;
    private BigDecimal montant;
    private String creditDebit;
    private int refCdg;
    private int refPaiment;
    private String modePaiment;
    private ReleveBancaire releveBancaire;
```

**Code that used to copy properties:**

```
public List<ReleveBancaire> getReleveBancaires() {
    List<ReleveBancaire> releveBancaireList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<ReleveBancaireEntity> releveBancaireEntityList = releveBancaireRepository.findAll();
    releveBancaireEntityList.forEach(r -> {
        ReleveBancaire releveBancaire = new ReleveBancaire();
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(r, releveBancaire);
        releveBancaireList.add(releveBancaire);});
    return releveBancaireList;
}
```

Comment: Your question doesn’t show any usage of `BeanUtils`. What’s the connection between your entity, its json representation, and the `BeanUtils` class?

Comment: Okay, now i'm working on multi maven modules I have a domain and entities what I'm trying to do is to copy from(entity) to (model) I'm doing a GET.METHOD to show me all ReleveBancaire which has a list LigneReleve that are presented in database. the weird thing is that copyproperties(from,to) works normal in 2.1.3.RELEASE but when I upgraded to 2.6.6 it doesn't work. I'll update my code snippet in question. Andy I have a question does beanUtils copy lists I mean like this situation ?

Answer (score 0):

After upgrade, copyProperties() method got the the logic to compare class type of source and target object.
If both the types the different even their fields name are matching then it will not go for copying the fields data.
For the work around you have to keep the type same by having common interface.

Here is that logic in BeanUtil class:

```html
boolean isAssignable =
                                (sourceResolvableType.hasUnresolvableGenerics() || targetResolvableType.hasUnresolvableGenerics() ?
                                        ClassUtils.isAssignable(writeMethod.getParameterTypes()[0], readMethod.getReturnType()) :
                                        targetResolvableType.isAssignableFrom(sourceResolvableType));

                        if (isAssignable) {
                            try {
                                if (!Modifier.isPublic(readMethod.getDeclaringClass().getModifiers())) {
                                    readMethod.setAccessible(true);
                                }
                                Object value = readMethod.invoke(source);
                                if (!Modifier.isPublic(writeMethod.getDeclaringClass().getModifiers())) {
                                    writeMethod.setAccessible(true);
                                }
                                writeMethod.invoke(target, value);
                            }
                            catch (Throwable ex) {
                                throw new FatalBeanException(
                                        "Could not copy property '" + targetPd.getName() + "' from source to target", ex);
                            }
```